# 18.04 partition problem or installation problem

Tags: system-installation

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on my hp 15cx0141tx which was having 128gb ssd and 1tb hdd. I was running on windows 10 on ssd. I formatted the whole ssd then only created '/' partition for boot and a efi partition . Further I installed the os but when i selected the restart option it stucked . Also when i restarted the laptop after login menu nothing happens. It only shows cursor. I need help.

Comment: "... after login menu". Which login menu do you mean? The Grub boot menu or the Ubuntu user login?

Comment: grub boot menu sir //////

Comment: Did you just create a `/` partition or did you re-install Ubuntu?